# The tag 'DataTrigger' does not exist in XML namespace?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am getting a really annoying error

Error   175 The tag 'DataTrigger' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Silverlight 5.  As far as I can tell the references are ok but obviously not, can someone tell me what is causing this please

I believe this may resolve the other question I raised earlier but cant test it because of this error

[Change DataTemplate to use depending on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020194/change-datatemplate-to-use-depending-on-condition)

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"             
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:iv="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  

mc:Ignorable="d"    
>
<UserControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectControl">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BlockType}" Value="Locked">
                        <Setter Property="DataTemplate"
                                Value="{StaticResource LockedClip}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BlockType}" Value="Unlocked">
                        <Setter Property="DataTemplate"
                                Value="{StaticResource UnlockedClip}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BlockType}" Value="Unlock">
                        <Setter Property="DataTemplate"
                                Value="{StaticResource UnlockClip}" />
                    </DataTrigger>                      
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="LockedClip">
  <my:SingleLockedFlexBlock Height="117"/>            
</DataTemplate>    

<DataTemplate x:Key="UnlockedClip">
  <my:SingleLockedFlexBlock Height="50"/>            
</DataTemplate>    

 <DataTemplate x:Key="UnlockClip">
   <my:SingleLockedFlexBlock Height="200"/>            
 </DataTemplate>
```

Hope someone can shed light on this?

Paul

Answer (score 2):

`DataTrigger` is not supported by default in Silverlight, but you could use the SDK from the [Blend Preview for SL5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9503) to obtain corresponding behavior.

You might want to take a look at:

- [*Expression SDK in Silverlight–DataTrigger Example*](http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/asills/archive/2011/05/11/expression-sdk-in-silverlight-datatrigger-example/) blog post
- [*Data Triggers in Silverlight*](http://www.nileshgule.com/2011/08/ngtweet-part-9-data-triggers-in.html) blog post
- the SO question [*What is the replacement for DataTrigger in Silverlight*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3529508/650012).

XAML code wise, I believe you need to change the following:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BlockType}" Value="Locked">
        <Setter Property="DataTemplate"
            Value="{StaticResource LockedClip}" />
    </DataTrigger>
    ...
```

into the following:

```
<iv:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BlockType}" Value="Locked">
        <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="DataTemplate"
            Value="{StaticResource LockedClip}" />
    </ei:DataTrigger>
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks I got passed the compile errors but still cant get this to work.  There is a comment saying add at the same level as Visual State for the control but I have no idea what level that is?

Comment: @Paul I have had some problems getting the trigger to activate myself, but I have at least updated my answer with some code that should hopefully be of help.

Comment: Thanks Anders I will try this when I get back to the office :)